# ubuntu 18.04 instance upgrade stop working

Tags: google-compute-engine

ubuntu 18.04 instance upgrade stop working

I created an instance in `gcp` and updated everything right here but when the restart stops working. How to solve it?

Comment: at least provide some error or a snapshot of the problem etc, your question is kind of vague

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/111079563) on ubuntu 18.04 and I recommend visiting this link to be able to check the progress of issue. Google currently working with Canonical on this issue.